# Showing System Date on form, jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, date, input

Im trying to get the system date with jquery and js to appear on a form input but it is not working

Heres my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
obtenerFecha();
$("#fecha").val(retornaFecha());
});

function obtenerFecha(){
var today = new Date();
var dd = today.getDate();
var mm = today.getMonth() + 1; //January is 0!
var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
if (dd < 10) {
    dd = '0' + dd;
}
if (mm < 10) {
    mm = '0' + mm;
}
var today = dd + '/' + mm + '/' + yyyy;
sessionStorage.setItem("fechaCreado", today);
}

function retornaFecha() {
var r = sessionStorage.getItem("fechaCreado");
return r;
}
```

and Here is the form:

```
<td class="info">Fecha de creación: </td>
<td class="inputs"><input name="fecha" id="fecha" value="" readonly="true"/></td>
```

I know it is simple but thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: Are you sure you have jquery included in your page? just copied your code in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/9smrjwxr/ and it is working as supposed with jquery included

Comment: If you have included jQuery, can you expand on "not working" - any errors in the console etc?

Comment: The problem has been solved... Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As written in my comment, make sure you have jquery included in your file. Else you can try using pure javascript, this will do the trick without jquery:

```
obtenerFecha();
document.getElementById('fecha').value = retornaFecha();


function obtenerFecha(){
var today = new Date();
var dd = today.getDate();
var mm = today.getMonth() + 1; //January is 0!
var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
if (dd < 10) {
    dd = '0' + dd;
}
if (mm < 10) {
    mm = '0' + mm;
}
var today = dd + '/' + mm + '/' + yyyy;
sessionStorage.setItem("fechaCreado", today);
}

function retornaFecha() {
var r = sessionStorage.getItem("fechaCreado");
return r;
}
```

**[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/8scet0o9/1/)**